# Build a Set of Node.Leaf.Id in one line with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 entities :

- Leaves
- Nodes, which contains Leaves.

I have a `Collection<Node>` and I am trying to build a `Set<Integer>` of all `Leaf` ids in one line of code. I feel that it might be possible with `Stream`s but until now, I can only dot it like this :

```
Set<Integer> leafIds = Sets.newHashSet();
root.getNodes()
    .forEach(node -> node.getLeaves()
              .forEach(leaf -> leafIds.add(leaf.getId())));
```

I don't like the part where I manually create the collection and add elements to it with method `Collection.add()` (not thread safe, dangerous and not optimized). I feel that it might be possible to do something like :

```
root.getNodes()
  .stream()
  .???
  .getLeaves()
  .map(Leaf::getId)
  .distinct()
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. With `flatMap` you can get from a `Stream<Node>` to a `Stream<Leaf>` of all the leaves of those nodes :

```
Set<Integer> leaves = root.getNodes().stream()
                          .flatMap (n -> n.getLeaves().stream())
                          .distinct()
                          .map(Leaf::getId)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```